# Ways of checking pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

According to the definition of pointwise convergence:
A sequence $f_m(x)$ of real valued functions defined on D a subset of real numbers
is said to be pointwise convergent to$f(d)$ at a point $d\epsilon D$ if for all $\epsilon$>0 there exists a $m_0$ such that $|f_m(d)-f(d)|$<$\epsilon$ for all $m>m_0$

to check pointwise convergence a given interval for a  given function , do we need to do all this work above? or we can simply find the $\lim m\to$infinity for the function $f_m(x)$ and if it exists then say that the function is pointwise convergent?

Comment: It's the same thing. If you find $\lim_{m \to \infty} f_m(d) = f(d)$ for all $d$ and write down the formal definition of limit, you'll just get what's in your first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help:)